# Binding not working inside the content presenter when its visibility is switched from collapsed state to visible state

Tags: wpf, contentpresenter

When the `Visibility` of `ContentPresenter` is set to `Collapsed` and change its `Visibility` at runtime, breaking the binding of the element kept inside its content.

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button"
            Width="100"
            Height="20"
            Margin="173,23,230,268"
            Click="button_Click"
            Content="Button" />

    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                      Margin="0,62,12,0"
                      Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ContentPresenter.Content>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox x:Name="test2"
                         Width="200"
                         Height="20" />
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Height="20"
                         Text="{Binding ElementName=test2,
                                        Path=Text,
                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ContentPresenter.Content>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

`Code`

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (contentPresenter.IsVisible == false)
    {
            contentPresenter.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else if (contentPresenter.IsVisible == true)
         {
             contentPresenter.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
         }
}
```

Any one help.

Answer (score 0):

if you put your content into a usercontrol your binding will work. if you check your output at runtime you would see that there is a binding error. meaning there is no element with "test2"

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button"
        Width="100"
        Height="20"
        Margin="173,23,230,268"
        Click="button_Click"
        Content="Button" />
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                  Margin="0,62,12,0"
                  Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ContentPresenter.Content>
            <WpfApplication1:UserControl1/>
        </ContentPresenter.Content>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

usercontrol

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="test2"
                     Width="200"
                     Height="20" />
        <TextBox Width="200"
                     Height="20"
                     Text="{Binding ElementName=test2,
                                    Path=Text,
                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```